# Would anything change if a qubit was made out of anti-matter?

Tags: quantum-circuit

If you had a QC system with an arbitrary number of qubits and an arbitrary number of anti-qubits (qubits made of anti-matter, e.g. a positron), how would the interactions (e.g. gates) and the circuit model in general change? (If at all?)

Comment: An interesting point. I believe a very important start point is to define a good mathematical representation of the interaction between a qubit and an anti-qubit.

Answer (score 1):

By calling something a "qubit" you are implicitly saying that it is a model of a mathematical qubit, i.e., it behaves exactly like a qubit is supposed to behave in the context of quantum information theory.

The details of experimental implementation will change based on what is used for the qubit model, but in the end the measured results of quantum information theory must be the same if you want to call such an entity a "qubit."